# SwiftUI transparent png becomes white (jpg)

Tags: swiftui

I have a png which is partically transparent, namely it has alpha channel. But when I used the following code, the transparent becomes white. I guess the alpha channel is missing. Do you know how to solve this problem? Thank you.

## This is the reproducible code.

```
Image("power")
.resizable()
.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
```

## This is the image

[image]

## This is the effect on simulator

[image]

Comment: Would you attach this image for testing?

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4. How do you present it? Would you provide minimal reproducible example?

Comment: My Xcode is 12.2. I am upgrading it.

Comment: @Asperi, still not working

Comment: @Asperi , I found the same code works fine in a new project but is not working in my current project. So some settings in this project caused the problem.

Comment: @Asperi, I found the reason. the compress for the png should be automatic, my previous is basic, that's why it renders white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this code to manage to show the transparent effect, but foreground colors are lost.

```
Color.black
    .frame(width: home.screenWidth-2*home.defaultPadding,
    height: home.screenWidth)
    .mask(Image("power")
      .resizable()
      .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit))
```

## Reason

Thank you for your helps so much!!!! Without your support, I cann't find the reason.
[image]

The compression for the png should be **automatic**, my project is inherited(basic) somehow, that's why it rendered white.

The code and image has no problem.

Comment: Where do I find this Image Set settings? I'm using Xcode V. 14.0.1

Answer (score 0):

That's what should happen. You've got an image with an alpha channel over a white background, so you can't see any of the white elements in your image. Change your Color Scheme to dark with .preferredColorScheme(.dark) and you'll see this:

[image]